# Convert CSV to Avro file in Java or scala

Tags: java, scala, csv, avro

Is there any library for convert CSV to Avro file in Java or scala.

I tried to google it, But not able to find any library for it.

Comment: CSV schema just names the fields while Avro also has types. How do you expect types for Avro scheme to be generated? Or do you have a known scheme expressed in classes in Java/Scala?

Comment: assuming you might know the schema... https://github.com/sspinc/csv2avro if not I think the answer from @Bala should be the correct one

Comment: this might also help https://github.com/uwegeercken/csv2avro

Answer (score 2):

By googling I found this article: https://dzone.com/articles/convert-csv-data-avro-data

quoting:

To convert csv data to Avro data using Hive we need to follow the steps below:

1. Create a Hive table stored as textfile and specify your csv delimiter also.
2. Load csv file to above table using "load data" command.
3. Create another Hive table using AvroSerDe.
4. Insert data from former table to new Avro Hive table using "insert overwrite" command.

Example: using a csv (student_id, subject_id, grade)

```
--1. Create a Hive table stored as textfile
USE test;
CREATE TABLE csv_table (
student_id INT,
subject_id INT,
marks INT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

--2. Load csv_table with student.csv data
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH "/path/to/student.csv" OVERWRITE INTO TABLE test.csv_table;

--3. Create another Hive table using AvroSerDe
CREATE TABLE avro_table
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
TBLPROPERTIES (
    'avro.schema.literal'='{
      "namespace": "com.rishav.avro",
      "name": "student_marks",
      "type": "record",
      "fields": [ { "name":"student_id","type":"int"}, { "name":"subject_id","type":"int"}, { "name":"marks","type":"int"}]
    }');

--4. Load avro_table with data from csv_table
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE avro_table SELECT student_id, subject_id, marks FROM csv_table;
```

Comment: But it is using Hive for converting. I want generic so we can use anywhere

Answer (score 2):

You could try this way (Spark 1.6).

```
people.csv

Michael, 29
Andy, 30
Justin, 19
```

Pyspark

```
file = sc.textFile("people.csv")
df = file.map(lambda line: line.split(',')).toDF(['name','age'])

>>> df.show()
+-------+---+
|   name|age|
+-------+---+
|Michael| 29|
|   Andy| 30|
| Justin| 19|
+-------+---+

df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save("peopleavro")
```

Peopleavro

```
{u'age': u' 29', u'name': u'Michael'}
{u'age': u' 30', u'name': u'Andy'}
{u'age': u' 19', u'name': u'Justin'}
```

Should you need to maintain data types, then create a schema and pass it.

```
schema = StructType([StructField("name",StringType(),True),StructField("age",IntegerType(),True)])

df = file.map(lambda line: line.split(',')).toDF(schema)
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
```

Now your avro has

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "topLevelRecord",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "name",
    "type" : [ "string", "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "age",
    "type" : [ "int", "null" ]
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use spark for this purpose or spark-shell (with options : --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro...) if it's an ad-hoc usage.

A sample code example :

`val df = spark.read.csv("example.csv")
df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save("example.avro")`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by :

- using the OpenCSV library to parse your CSV (http://opencsv.sourceforge.net)
- using the json-smart library (https://github.com/netplex/json-smart-v2) to output the Avro JSON (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Avro for the schema)